# Combining P values of two independent experiments

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I am working with two cell lines studying the impact of a certain chemical on these cells. I have identified some key differences between the chemical expressing and non-expressing cells. However, statistical analysis of my data (I use Student's t-test to compare the differences between the two groups) shows no significance despite having clear differences which are due to low sample size (2). I only have two cell lines to do my experiments and I repeat each experiment at least once (two independent experiments). I was wondering what the best method would be to combine the p values obtained from two independent experiments.

Answer (score 1):

> statistical analysis of my data (I use Student's t-test to compare the differences between the two groups) shows no significance despite having clear differences which are due to low sample size

In my opinion, you should present good biological reasons that allow you to say that the differences are, as you say, clear. I think this is more convincing and informative than forcing the data to show significance from such a small sample size.

Alternatively, or in addition to, it could be more sensible to apply some transformation to the data that makes biological sense and fits better with the assumptions of the t-test. Also, you could consider analyzing the two experiments in a single framework (e.g. anova, linear model) that would have a bit more power.

But to answer your question, you can look at [Fisher's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method) and similar approaches (google *combine p-values*)

Comment: By ANOVA or linear model you mean simply combine the data from the two experiments and add an indicator variable for experiment #1 or #2? I think that would be the option I'd consider first.